# SynchronizationLockException using mutexes

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am getting a SynchronizationLockException inside a mutex lock while trying to call Monitor.Wait(object). What should I change?

```
static Mutex mutex;
static readonly object monitorKey;
condition = true;
mutex.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            while (condition)  
            {
                Monitor.Wait(monitorKey); // exception is thrown
            }
            isAnyoneWriting = true;         
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an value (`new object();`) to `monitorKey` on creation (since it's static and readonly).

After that, you must acquire the lock before waiting on it:

```
while (condition)
{
   lock(monitorKey)
   {
      Monitor.Wait(monitorKey); // exception is thrown
   }
}
```

Or you could reverse the order and have the lock surround the while to avoid unnecessary lock -> exit cycles.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot the assignments, as I have them inside a constructor. Do you happen to know why mutexes do not work as a lock in this case?

Comment: If you assign a value to `monitorKey` in your constructor, that's fine. Regarding the mutex, that has nothing to do with the problem, or the solution. As I wrote, *you must acquire the lock before waiting on it*. That means locking the object you plan to wait on. That's just how the API is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me from a disaster ;]

Comment: lock surrounding everything would not be a good design, will lead to lot of contention among threads, just lock the required portion where unsafe structure is modified / written

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - that usually what the `Monitor.Wait` function is used for. you're releasing the lock for the duration of the wait. I merely noted that it might make sense to do the lock just outside the while since no other "work" is being done there.

Comment: @Amit My understanding is this might not be complete code, there could code inserted on either side of lock in the while loop in the real scenario, Bringing everything under lock may look attractive for those who might not deliberate the issues arising out of it

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The lock should surround any logic that needs to be thread safe. That said, the wait allows you to be a tiny bit more liberal about it since you're allowing other threads to capture the lock and hence prevent deadlock conditions. That freedom can be utilized to improve performance since releasing the lock and "immediately" trying to reacquire it only to release it once again (inside wait) can generate a lot of useless context switches. In the end, every piece of logic has a right way of doing things, and I just stated its possible.